# Trying to align text and an icon html/css

Tags: html, css

I am trying to align an icon with some text like this:

[image]

however it comes out like this:

[image]

```css
.percent {
  float: right;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.card-icon {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="blue">
      <p class="text-center"> Self Managed <img src="app/assets/images/star.png" alt=""> </p>
    </div>
    <p class="percent"> <img class="card-icon" src="app/assets/images/self.png" alt="Smiley face"> 1% </p>
```

EDIT ****

With the last answer provided it shows up like this: 
[image]

Comment: If CSS flex is an option I would just go with that.. you can pretty easily Google CSS flex guide

Comment: I will achieve on flex property. For the parent div give the css property "display:flex; align-items:center;". That's it now the children div look's good as per your design.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.card-icon {float: left;margin-right:10px; }
```

```html
    <style type="text/css">
     
    </style>
    <div class="col-md-4">
     <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header" id="blue">
       <p class="text-center"> Self Managed <img src="app/assets/images/star.png" alt=""> </p>
      </div>
      <div class = "percent">
       <img class="card-icon" src="app/assets/images/self.png" alt="Smiley face">
       <div class="card-txt"> 1% </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.card-icon {float: left;position:relative;z-index:1; }
.card-icon:after {content:"=";position:relative; left:25px;}
.percent .card-txt:nth-of-type(1) {text-align:center;position:relative; left:-55px;}
.card-txt {text-align:center; width:400px;background:#ddd;}
```

```html
  <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="card">
          <div class="card-header" id="blue">
              <p class="text-center"> Self Managed <img src="app/assets/images/star.png" alt=""> </p>
          </div>
          <div class = "percent">
              <img class="card-icon" src="app/assets/images/self.png" alt="Smiley face">
              <div class="card-txt"> 1% </div>
              <div class="card-txt"> service tax + VAT </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use inline-block instead of floats:

```css
.card-icon {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.card-icon:after {
  content: "=";
  position: absolute;
  right: -16px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.percent .card-txt:nth-of-type(1) {
  text-align: center;
}

.card-txt {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 24px;
}

.block {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="blue">
      <p class="text-center"> Self Managed <img src="app/assets/images/star.png" alt=""> </p>
    </div>
    <div class="percent">
      <img class="card-icon" src="app/assets/images/self.png" alt="Smiley face">
      <div class="card-txt">
        <span class="block">1%</span>
        <span class="block">service tax + VAT</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the best solution is an old solution. Using HTML tables allows you to control vertical height with a high level of browser support, and backwards compatibility. Using this approach also make the element responsive. Other solutions that adopt the relative/absolute position method can suffer when resizing browser window size.

```css
table {
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

table tr td {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: relative;
}

table tr .number-cell {
  padding-top:10px;
  width: 80px;  
}

table tr .number-cell .value {
  margin-top: 4px;
    font-size: 42px;
}

table tr .number-cell .sub-heading {
  background: grey
}

table tr .equal-cell {
  width: 0px;
}

table tr td img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>MY WEBSITE</h1>
  
  <table>
    <tr>
    
      <td class="image-cell">
        <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/100/100"/>
      </td>
      
      <td class="equal-cell"> 
        <span class="equal">=</span>
      </td>
      
      <td class="number-cell">
        <div class="value">1%</div>
        <div class="sub-heading">service fee</div>
      </td>
      
    </tr>
  </table>
 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want more controle you can use flex styling. An example:

```css
.card {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  
  width: 500px;
}
.card-header {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  
  padding: 10px;
  
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  font-size: 24px;
}
.card-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  
  background-color: gray;
}
.card-header > img {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
   <div class="card-header">
     <span>Self Managed</span>
     <img src="app/assets/images/star.png" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="card-content">
    <img class="card-icon" src="app/assets/images/self.png" alt="Smiley face">
    <span>1%</span>
  </div>
</div>
```